# Ruby lambda execution with should in Spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, lambda

Sorry, I'm newbie in Ruby.

I have such code in RSpec test:

```
it "if Add get empty string as parameter return 0" do
        lambda { StringCalculator.new(5).Add("") }.should == 0
end
```

It doesn't work because lambda doesn't have a method "should". And the most important thing is that lambda doesn't execute in such case! I'm not sure, please tell me if I'm not right.

Then I try such code:

```
it "if Add get empty string as parameter return 0" do
        lambda { StringCalculator.new(5).Add("") }.call.should == 0
end
```

and everything is okay,because I use the method "call" and as a result lambda executes.

I guess that if we use the method "call" to lambda then lambda executes.

But then I try such code WITHOUT CALL method for lambda:

```
it "if Add get empty string as parameter return 0" do
        lambda { StringCalculator.new().Add("") }.should raise_exception ArgumentError
end
```

I don't use "call" method but somehow the test is passed, it means that lambda was executed and because of `.new().` with no parameters, exception was thrown.

Please help me to understand why in third case exception was detected if lambda shouldn't has been executed? I don't use call.

In the third case with "call" method result is the same and I understand why.

Thanks for help.

In addition code of StringCalculator class:

```
class StringCalculator

def initialize(x)
    @x = x
end

def Add(str)
    if str == ""
        0
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`raise_error`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-5/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) needs a block to execute and in your last example, you give a block (i.e. your lambda).

In your first example, if you want to use `should` with an [equality matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-5/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers), such as `==` you would just have:

```
StringCalculator.new(5).Add("").should == 0
```

By the way, in newer versions of RSpec you would write it as:

```
expect(StringCalculator.new(5).Add("")).to eq 0
```